# Get all components linked to a datasource

Tags: delphi, dataset, datasource, delphi-2010

I am currently trying to change properties for hug components depending on state of other component using what RTTI provide but i can't figure out how to retrieve all links between 
DataSource and DataAware components...

that's what i would like to achieve

1. Get all components linked to specific DataSource something [like](http://delphi.cjcsoft.net//viewthread.php?tid=43097).
2. iterate through all those components.
3. if the component accept ReadOnly property (by using RTTI i guess) i would like to change the property depending on the DataSet state:

   `if DataSource.DataSet.state = dsbrowse then Component[i].ReadOnly := True`
   `if DataSource.DataSet.state = dsEdit then Component[i].ReadOnly := False`

thanks in advance for help

Comment: What's wrong with the solution shown in your link?

Comment: @Uwe Raabe could you provide some explanation the solution not clear enough at least for me..

Comment: what exactly is not clear for you? ask specific questions about what specific lines you do not understand. Otherwise you question means "read a textbook to me" and that is not good kind of questions. http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve, because setting the `TDataSource.AutoEdit` property to `False` should automatically disable editing in the controls until you manually change the `DataSet.State` to one of the ones in `dsEditModes`.

With that being said, this will do what you're asking. It uses an accessor class to access the `protected` `DataLinks` list in a `TDataSource`, and then checks to see if it's a `TFieldLink` and also if it has the `ReadOnly` property.

```
// No Delphi version provided, so uses "older style" RTTI
uses
  TypInfo, DB, DBCtrls;

type
  THackDataSource=class(TDataSource);  // accessor class

procedure SetDataSetControlsReadOnly(const DataSource: TDataSource);
var
  i: Integer;
  DS: THackDataSource;
  DL: TDataLink;
  EnableIt: Boolean;
begin
  EnableIt := DataSource.State in dsEditModes;
  DS := THackDataSource(DataSource.DataSet);

  for i := 0 to DS.DataLinks.Count - 1 do
  begin
    DL := DS.DataLinks[i];
    if DL is TFieldDataLink then
    begin
      if IsPublishedProp(DL, 'ReadOnly') then
        SetOrdProp(DL, 'ReadOnly', Ord(EnableIt));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Ken White thanks in fact i wasn't aware of `TDataSource.AutoEdit` your code give me a lot of what i need about Delphi version it's D2010 i forget to mentioned it earlier...